# Confused with Stripe payment_method

Tags: django, django-views, stripe-payments, payment

I have been using Stripe inside my Django project with no problems so far, everything is working, however I am confused about the `payment_method` parameter. At the moment I have it set to `pm_card_visa` because that's what the documentation told me to do, however I believe this is causing me problems as when I put in a dummy Mastercard number that Stripe gives you, it is still defaulting to use the default `4242 4242 4242` card.

How can I dynamically set the payment_method variable?

Comment: Are you sure you've followed the documentation mentioned on https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create

Answer (score 2):

`pm_card_visa` is a 'shortcut' to the 4242424242424242 test card.  You instead need to put in whatever Payment Method ID you get from Elements.  https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment

Answer (score 0):

```
$create = $stripe->paymentIntents->create([
    'amount'    => 100,
    'currency'  => 'usd',
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  ]);

$id = $create->id;
$method = $stripe->paymentMethods->create([
    'type' => 'card',
    'card' => [
      'number' => '4242424242424242',
      'exp_month' => 12),
      'exp_year' => 2022 ),
      'cvc' => '314',
    ],
  ]);
$payment = $stripe->paymentIntents->confirm(
    $id,
    ['payment_method' => $method]
);
```